# Changing the component selector failed compilation

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**It is Angular CLI 13.1.3**

I have a component inside a module. Module name is auth and component name is login. By default, login component had selector name "app-login" which I changed into "login"

and placed the new name in app.component.html

**Code in login component inside auth module**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

It showed following errors.

> src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'login' is not a known
> element:
>
> 1. If 'login' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

[image]

**Do I need to make further changes for login selector change?**

**Code In Auth Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

**Code in App Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthModule } from './Auth/Auth.module';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: did you try restarting the compilation ? Live reload may have trouble for such big changes

Comment: Yes, I did. Also, when I try revering the selector, I get same exact error for the original selector which was showing for changed one.

Comment: can you show the content of your AuthModule ? Does it export `LoginComponent` ?

Comment: updated the question, please let me know if there is anything else missing or needed further info. Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AppComponent to be able to call LoginComponent, your AuthModule has to export LoginComponent:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    LoginComponent // <=== here
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```